# Select variables with different names

Tags: r, select

I have some DF’s with different variable names, but they have the same content. Unfortunately, my files have no pattern, but I am now trying to standardize them. For example, I have these 4 DF’s and I would like to select only one variable:

```
KEY_WIN <- c(123,456,789)
COUNTRY <- c("USA","FRANCE","MEXICO")
DF1 <- data.frame(KEY_WIN,COUNTRY)

KEY_WINN <- c(12,55,889)
FOOD <- c("RICE","TOMATO","MANGO")
CAR <- c("BMW","FERRARI","TOYOTA")
DF2 <- data.frame(KEY_WINN,FOOD,CAR)

ID <- c(555,698,33)
CITY <- c("NYC","LONDON","PARIS")
DF3 <- data.frame(ID,CITY)

NUMBER <- c(3,436,1000)
OCEAN <- c("PACIFIC","ATLANTIC","INDIAN")
DF4 <- data.frame(NUMBER,OCEAN)
```

I would like to create a routine to select only the variables KEY_WIN, KEY_WINN, ID, NUMBER. My expected result would be:

```
DF_FINAL<- data.frame(KEY=c(123,456,789, 12,55,889, 555,698,33, 3,436,1000))
```

How would I select only those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways I would imagine you could approach this.

First, you could put your data frames in a list:

```
listofDF <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4)
```

Then, you could `bind_rows` to add the data frames together, and then `coalesce` to merge into one column.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(listofDF) %>%
  mutate(KEY = coalesce(KEY_WIN, KEY_WINN, ID, NUMBER)) %>%
  select(KEY)

    KEY
1   123
2   456
3   789
4    12
5    55
6   889
7   555
8   698
9    33
10    3
11  436
12 1000
```

If you knew that the *first* column was always your `KEY` column, you could simply do:

```
KEY = unlist(lapply(listofDF, "[[", 1))
```

This would extract the first column from all of your data frames:

```
 [1]  123  456  789   12   55  889  555  698   33    3  436 1000
```